# WSO2 ESB Data Services

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

While creating Data service, I see 'Enable Batch Request', 'Enable Box Carring' options while developing SQL.

It is clear that these are used for processing batch records.

Could you please let me know how many records(100, 200 or what is the default setting) are handled by these two options at once when invoked.

If I want to change the default settings, how it can be done.

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: it's not limited by DSS itself, it depends how large request can you send and process, how much memory can you spare and how much garbage are your server able to clean..

Comment: There should be some default settings. If I want to change it as per my requirements, then what are the probable options?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default setting, you pass one record it works , you pass 100 records it works, it all depends upon your request and you cannot change anything in it , if you want to limit the number of records then you can do that using wso2 esb, so wso2 esb you frame a request with limited records and then pass to DSS the advantage is that you can control the request in ESB as per your requirement.